# div within a div which grows upwards instead of downwards

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` within a `div` and the `div` inside has the following styles:

```
#tbs_pagelists {
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 390px;
  left: -950px;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

What I am experiencing is that when I add text in the `tbs_pagelists` `div` the text increases the size of this div upwards and vertically, rather than downwards... in other words the bottom of the div is at 390px from the top left corner of the containing `div` but when text is added that bottom stays there and the div grows towards the top left of the containing `div`... how can I make it so the `div` grows downwards instead?

Comment: Post HTML also or fiddle

Comment: html and fiddle plez www.fiddle.net

Comment: Post html markup & full css

Comment: http://indivisiblemusic.com/index.php?p=Releases&ms=m2&l=en&

Comment: did you guys get the link?

Comment: The link you provide has an load error: file `http://www.indivisiblemusic.com/wp-content/themes/barebones/js/app.js` not found. Also, is not clear where the `tbs_pagelists` class is: i did not found in the code.